# Moving my right sidebar more to the right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move my right sidebar over to the right more. Just like how my left sidebar is. My website is [marikastravels.com](http://marikastravels.com)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please write particular code with CSS so that stackoverflow community can help you out!

Comment: I am new to web development and am only customizing a wordpress theme. I am not familiar with the coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your CSS change width to

```
.yui-t2 .sidebar { 
width: 18.5%; 
float: right;
}
```

Also, this will give more room for your center div which you can increase too e.g.

```
.yui-t2 .main-content {
width: 78.5%;
float: left;
}
```

I tested the above code in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Both works.

```
<ul class="xoxo" style="float: right;">
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
...
</ul>
```

or

```
<style type="text/css">
.xoxo{
float:right;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#right-primary {
  float: right;
}
```

I suggest bootstrap for all the other problems